# Deploying Swing application with JavaFX content

Tags: java, swing, ant, intellij-idea, javafx

I've written a Swing application that uses a JavaFX component and I'd like to package it for distribution, however I haven't been able to figure it out.

In Intellij Idea I selected File-> Project Structure-> artifacts and chose "from module". Next I selected Build-> Generate Ant Build and generated some Ant files. I modified the is line:

```
<fx:application id="JReader_id" name="JReader" mainClass="com.facetoe.jreader.JReader"/>
```

as described [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/packaging_swing_apps_with_integrated) to:

```
<fx:application id="JReader_id" name="JReader" mainClass="com.facetoe.jreader.JReader" toolkit="swing"/>
```

to indicate its a Swing application. Finally I built the `.jar` using Build-> Build Artifacts in Intellij and the .jar was created without errors. However when I attempt to run the .jar I get this error:

```
    ⇒ java -jar out/artifacts/JReader/JReader.jar
    java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.javafx.main.Main can not access a member of class com.facetoe.jreader.JReader with modifiers "public static"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:109)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:261)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:253)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:714)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:871)
```

It looks like it cannot run the main method for some reason... Does anyone have any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out. The class containing my method was not `public`, so I made it `public` and everything works fine now.